# "Se puede pagar con tarjeta" vs "es posible pagar con tarjeta" in Spain?

Tags: uso-de-palabras, españa

Are these equally used in Spain, or is the first option more common?

- ¿Se puede pagar con tarjeta?
- ¿Es posible pagar con tarjeta?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The difference is minimal.

*¿Se puede pagar con tarjeta?* is slightly more colloquial, and one might use it more often to ask friends if a particular place accepts card payments.

When asking the waiter/seller directly, one might more often say *¿Es posible pagar con tarjeta?* or *¿Puedo pagar con tarjeta?*. In any case, in Spain, interaction with waiters or sellers is usually colloquial enough that it will not make much of a difference.

Comment: This answer works well for Mexico too.